# how to return last index on the multiindex in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I want to have a return value from a multiindex. Here is what i mean:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['2022-05-22', '2022-05-23', '2022-05-24', '2022-05-25'], ['a', 'b', 'c']])
data = pd.Series(np.random.rand(12), index=index)
data.index.names = ['date', 'var']
data
```

Will result on:

```
date        var
2022-05-22  a      0.757109
            b      0.149882
            c      0.285188
2022-05-23  a      0.020857
            b      0.274391
            c      0.048735
2022-05-24  a      0.459640
            b      0.585560
            c      0.073415
2022-05-25  a      0.991139
            b      0.681288
            c      0.284437
dtype: float64
```

If i type: `data.index[-1]`
i will get: `('2022-05-25', 'c')`

How to get only `2022-05-25` as a result without the second index?
Also how to get `2022-05-24` (the second lowest level 0 index) as a return value?

Comment: Is your MultiIndex always sorted? What if not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the wanted level and keep the unique values:

```
l = data.index.get_level_values('date').unique()

l[-1]
# '2022-05-25'

l[-2]
# '2022-05-24'
```

Other approach, `unstack`:

```
idx = data.unstack().index

idx[-1]
# '2022-05-25'

idx[-2]
# '2022-05-24'
```

Answer (score 1):

what happens when you run `type(data.index[-1])`?

This means you can access this the same way in which you would any other `tuple` in python.

`data.index[-1][0]`